# Python: TCP Server with public IP

Tags: python, tcp, tcpserver

My code:

```
sIP = "20.20.20.20" #My original IP comes from here > whatismyip.com
sPort = 4567
bSize = 2048

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((sIP, sPort))
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/d0nkey/Scripts/TCPServer.py", line 19, in <module>
    s.bind((sIP, sPort))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

The same code works fine using localhost and my local ip instead.

How to set up a TCP server on my public IP?

[OS: Linux elementaryOS 86x64]

Comment: I think you need to configure your socket binding to use your local IP and configure your router's firewall to allow incoming tcp requests to port 4567, and configure your router's network address translation (NAT) to forward requests for port 4567 to your local IP.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I don't have access to my routers settings :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only bind to an address that is available on the network interfaces of the operating system that is running your program. You have a Linux. So try to open a terminal and type in "ifconfig" to see all available interfaces and their addresses. It is also possible to bind to all available addresses, using the special "0.0.0.0" address. Please note that whatismyip.org tells you the public ip that connects your inner network to the internet. If you are behind a firewall/NAT then you need to setup port forwarding, and redirect requests from the firewall/gateway address to the local address where your program is listening. If you have no access to the firewall settings, then you cannot listen on its public address.

Answer (score 2):

You have to bind it to your local IP (depending on which network card to use) and make use of port forwarding (NAT) in your router to forward the traffic of the public IP (for the TCP server) to your local IP. In that way your TCP server will be available remotely.